# See contents of table variable using immediate / locals windows

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

In SSMS and its immediate or locals window, is there a way to see the contents of table variable?
I can select and view the value of scalars, but I can't seem to find a way to query the contents of tables or even run

```
SELECT * FROM @someTableVarInMySproc
```

in the immediate window. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry, this is not possible in current versions of Management Studio. It has been asked for, and it's been stated that they are considering something similar in a future version. You can vote and add constructive comments on the following items, though there is no guarantee they'll ever actually do it:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/623353

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/582167

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/454870

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/363054

---

The first item in that list has an interesting workaround:

[image]

In addition to the obvious caveat that you may not be able to inject additional code to capture the data in an XML variable (because after all, if you can do this, you could also add old-school debugging techniques like `SELECT * FROM @table`), and the cumbersome nature of trying to read this information from XML, Management Studio 2012 crashed on me the first time I tried to do this - so if you're going to try it, make sure you do so in an isolated instance.